# How to annotate Python function using return type of another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-hinting

I am looking for some analogue of **decltype** in C++. What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

```
def f(a: int) -> List[Tuple(int, float)]
def g(a: List[int]) -> List[decltype(f)]
```

So the idea is to use type annotation of another function. 
The solution I found looks somehow clumsy:

```
def g(a: List[int])->f.__annotations__['return']
```

Basically, the question is whether there exists something like **decltype** (perhaps it should be called "return_type") or whether it's planned in further versions. I have also written a small function that illustrates possible use of this functionality:

```
def return_type(f: Callable):
   try:
       return get_type_hints(f)['return']
   except(KeyError, AttributeError):
       return Any
def g() -> return_type(f):
```

**UPD** As was suggested by Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard we can also use **get_type_hints** instead of **annotations**

Comment: You mean like: `def decltype(function): return function.__annotations__['return']` ? :)

Comment: @cowbert Yes, I just added a similar example :) Actually, I am confused that there is no function for this kind of things, and I wonder whether is something wrong with this attitude.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing like that *currently* exists and no issue on [the tracker for typing](https://github.com/python/typing/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen) seem to indicate that it is planned. You're always welcome to create an issue and see how this is welcomed.

Currently your approach does the trick (that is assigns a type), the only change I'd introduce would be to use [`get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) from `typing` rather than grabbing the `__annotations__` attribute directly. Coupled with `.get` (since it returns a dict), could make this shorter, too:

```
def return_type(f):
    return get_type_hints(f).get('return', Any)

def g() -> return_type(f):
```

Which can of course be removed from the function and used in a single line if you're so inclined.

If the possibility of random objects being supplied to `return_type` exits, you'll need to catch the `TypeError` it raises and return your default `Any`:

```
def return_type(f):
    try:
        return get_type_hints(f).get('return', Any)
    except TypeError:
        return Any
```

Of course since this assigns a type dynamically you can't expect static type checkers to catch it, you need static hinting for that.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning get_type_hints! I will add this to the question text

Comment: @ig-melnyk note that with `get_type_hints` this really becomes a one-liner if you really want it to :-)

Comment: Perhaps we should still check for AttributeError in case it wont be Callable?

Comment: @ig-melnyk Oh, of course, if something other than a function (in `3.5`) and other than function, class, module (in `3.6+`) might be passed in you'd need to do that, I wasn't aware that was the case.

Comment: This seems like it wouldn't play well with current static analysis tools.