# Typing - function return value type same as a type of an expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Consider the code:

```
def foo() -> ??:
     return bar()
```

How can I say that I want the return type of `foo` to be the same as the return type of `bar()`?

In C++ I could use `decltype`, something along the lines of:

```
auto foo() -> decltype(bar()) {
    return bar();
}
```

I couldn't find Python's equivalent. Is there any?

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124771/how-to-annotate-python-function-using-return-type-of-another-function

Comment: Do you need an explicit type? What will be inferred in its absence?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did the test, and you're right - it looks the correct type was inferred (at least as far as syntax completion in my editor goes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `bar` is defined, you can access its signature

```
In [1] from inspect import signature

In [2]: def bar(a: int) -> float: 
   ...:     return float(a)                                         
   ...:                                                             

In [3]: def foo(a: int) -> signature(bar).return_annotation: 
   ...:     return bar(a)                                           
   ...:                                                             

In [4]: signature(foo)                                              
Out[4]: <Signature (a: int) -> float>
```

That being said, I'm not sure you need that if you do this for static  type checking, because `foo`'s return type can be inferred from `bar`'s (at least PyCharm's static analyser tends to do that).

Answer (score 0):

Python's built-in typing library enables creating [custom types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#distinct), you can describe a new type class and couple both functions with this class as a return value.