# Type hint for wrapping methods after inheritance

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pylance

Suppose I have a base class which handles common functionality in a wrapper method (such as logging) and inheriting classes implementing specific functionality by overriding a private method.

```py
from typing import Any


class Base:
    def do_something(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        # Do some logging here ...
        result = self._actually_do_something(*args, **kwargs)
        # ... and here.
        return result

    def _actually_do_something(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        raise NotImplementedError


class Child1(Base):
    def _actually_do_something(self, x: int) -> str:
        return str(x)
```

I would like to annotate `Base` such that `do_something` has the same signature as `_actually_do_something` for any inheriting class for static type analysis (e.g., using mypy or pylance in VS Code). How might I go about that?

<s>In other words, I would like the two following print statements to both yield `{'x': <class 'int'>, 'return': <class 'str'>}`.</s>

```py
# prints: {'return': typing.Any}
print(Child1.do_something.__annotations__)
# prints: {'x': <class 'int'>, 'return': <class 'str'>}
print(Child1._actually_do_something.__annotations__)
```

## Related

This question is not unrelated to [How to annotate Python function using return type of another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124771/how-to-annotate-python-function-using-return-type-of-another-function) button the discussion did not resolve the question of *static* type hints.

## Things I've tried

### Option A: generics

- Pros: Gets the return type correct.
- Cons: Requires manual return type annotation on class decoration, doesn't generate type hints for the arguments.

```py
R = TypeVar("R")


class BaseA(Generic[R]):
    def do_something(self, *args, **kwargs) -> R: ...


class ChildA1(BaseA[str]):
    def _actually_do_something(self, x: int) -> str: ...
```

### Option B: decorator with generics and another layer of indirection

- Pros: Gets the return type and signature correct.
- Cons: Requires another level of indirection and `propagate_types` call in each child class, may cause issues with deeper inheritance.

```py
def propagate_types(actual: Callable, hinted: R) -> R:
    return actual


class BaseB:
    def _inner_do_something(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        return self._actually_do_something(*args, **kwargs)

    def _actually_do_something(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        raise NotImplementedError


class ChildB1(BaseB):
    def _actually_do_something(self, x: int) -> str:
        pass

    do_something = propagate_types(BaseB._inner_do_something, _actually_do_something)
```

Comment: Use a `TypeVar` instead of `Any`.  Make Base a `Generic[T]` that returns a `T` from those methods, and then have `Child` inherit `Base[str]` so that its `T` is `str`.

Comment: "In other words, I would like the two following print statements to both yield ..." That is  not really what you want. You want static analysis to understand that, but that is not identical what the actual contents of `.__annotations__`

Comment: Yeah, good point. I should've added what I tried. Updated above.

Comment: If the use case for this is logging, maybe a decorator would be a better approach than inheritance?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're doing with `Base`'s annotations? Do you have common API which only looks at `Base`, or do the users of the API know about `BaseB` and `ChildB1` too? (if the latter is not true, you're out of luck)

Comment: Also, I believe the common way to do what you want in your example is to make the logging functionality a decorator and implement `do_something` in all your classes, then decorate `do_something` with the logger. That's easier to statically type as well.

Comment: Yes, I agree that decorators would have been a good choice here. However, this is an existing library with downstream users (and requiring a decorator on inheriting classes in user-code would break backwards compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the return type by making it a `TypeVar`:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class Base(Generic[T]):
    def do_something(self, *args, **kwargs) -> T:
        # Do some logging here ...
        result = self._actually_do_something(*args, **kwargs)
        # ... and here.
        return result

    def _actually_do_something(self, *args, **kwargs) -> T:
        raise NotImplementedError


class Child1(Base[str]):
    def _actually_do_something(self, *args, **kwargs) -> str:
        return str(args[0])

reveal_type(Child1().do_something(42))  # str
```

Note that having `Child` take a more restrictive set of arguments than its superclass violates the Liskov substitution principle; you will need its `_actually_do_something` to accept any arguments that the parent class would be expected to handle.

Comment: yeah, and the arguments will have to be annotated or else they are implicitly `Any`.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a bit more context above.